# cargar en una escena varias escenas des escenas ya cargadas

Tags: javafx

necesito cargar desde un boton en unmenu q es un archivo FXML cargado segun el usuario q se autentica otra escena a un panel de la escena q contiene este menu como hago?

de esta forma cargo el menu

Principal.fxml desde Su controlador

private void cargarSession() {

```
    Parent root = null;
    String menu = "";

    try {

     // elige el menu segun el rol admin o estandard
        if(cuentaactiva.getUser_root()==0){
          menu = "/pVistas/includes/MenuAdmin";
        }else{

          menu = "/pVistas/includes/MenuDefault";        
        }

     //nombre de la Cuenta autenticada
        Lbl_user.setText(cuentaactiva.getUser_name());

     //cargar el menu
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(menu+".fxml"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PrincipalController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // pone el menu en su lugar   
if(!ContentMenu.getChildren().isEmpty())
{
    ContentMenu.getChildren().remove(0);   
    ContentMenu.getChildren().add(root);
}else{
    ContentMenu.getChildren().add(root);}
}
```

el menu admin por ejemplo tiene 4 botones y necesito q cuando de en el boton cuentas me carge en el mismo padre pero en otro contenedor que es un Pane el FXML correspondiente.

para ello he hecho esto, una funcion q me lo cargue y poder llamarla desde ese boton pero no sale nada o da error de null pointer

Principal.FXML desde su controlador 
 @FXML
    public void cargarfunciones (String url){

```
    Pane root = new Pane();
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(url+".fxml"));
        Contentpane.getChildren().clear();
        Contentpane.getChildren().add(root);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PrincipalController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

asi la llamo desde el menuAdmin.FXML desde su controlador

```
@FXML
private void OpnCuentas(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
  String url = "/pVistas/Subinterfaces/Cuentas";

  PrincipalController PpalController = new PrincipalController();
  PpalController.cargarfunciones(url);
}
```

En Espera de ayuda. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estos metodos te pueden ayudar en lo que deseas hacer. Mi primera sugerencia es siempre desacoplar el codigo para que no tengas todo junto sino que siempre puedas reutilizar los algoritmos.

```
public Parent cargarFXML(String rutaFXML) {
    // ejemplo para escribir la ruta del FXML
    // /stdxml/vista/auxiliares/Modelo1.fxml

    Parent root = null;

    try {

       root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(rutaFXML));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VentanaImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return root;
}
```

el siguiente es para convertir la ventana en modal

```
private Stage ventanaModal(Parent root){
    final Stage ventana = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setFill(null);


    ventana.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ventana.setScene(scene);
    ventana.setResizable(false);
    ventana.sizeToScene();

  return ventana;
}
```

Para cerrar la ventana

```
public void cerrarVentana(Node nodo){
   Stage stg = (Stage) nodo.getScene().getWindow();
   stg.close();
}
```

Aquí seria un método para cargar una ventana. Por simplicidad solo se coloco lo necesario. Puedes modificarlo y mostrar cualquier scene deseado

```
public void mensajeria(String titulo, String contenido) {
   Parent root = this.cargarFXML("/stdxml/vista/emergentes/Mensaje.fxml");


    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            new VentanaImpl().ventanaModal(root).showAndWait();
       }
   });


}
```